# Arrangement of data in specific sequence using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am working on a project where I have to perform the important step to sort data.
The problem where i got stuck is to sort in specific sequence in pandas.

Here is the data

```
clinic_id   client_id   patient_id  Attribute
97142       1891        3423    Service Date
97142       1891        3423    Service Date
97142       1891        3423    Service Date
97142       1891        3423    Qty
97142       1891        3423    Qty
97142       1891        3423    Qty
97142       1891        3423    Product
97142       1891        3423    Product
97142       1891        3423    Product
97142       1891        3423    Days Last Dose
97142       1891        3423    Days Last Dose
97142       1891        3423    Days Last Dose
97142       1891        3423    Amount
97142       1891        3423    Amount
97142       1891        3423    Amount
97142       1891        3423    Age
97142       1891        3423    Age
97142       1891        3423    Age
```

I want to arrange thee Attributes column into below format.

> Service Date, Product, Qty, Amount, Age, Days Last Dose

```
clinic_id   client_id   patient_id  Attribute
    97142   1891    3423    Service Date
    97142   1891    3423    Product
    97142   1891    3423    Qty
    97142   1891    3423    Amount
    97142   1891    3423    Age
    97142   1891    3423    Days Last Dose
    97142   1891    3423    Service Date
    97142   1891    3423    Product
    97142   1891    3423    Qty
    97142   1891    3423    Amount
    97142   1891    3423    Age
    97142   1891    3423    Days Last Dose
    97142   1891    3423    Service Date
    97142   1891    3423    Product
    97142   1891    3423    Qty
    97142   1891    3423    Amount
    97142   1891    3423    Age
    97142   1891    3423    Days Last Dose
```

Need help how can I achieve that.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `pd.CategoricalDtype` so that you can order the 'Attributes' by any random order. Also create a `cumcount` level to sort by:

```
order = ['Service Date', 'Product', 'Qty', 'Amount', 'Age', 'Days Last Dose']

df['Attribute'] = df['Attribute'].astype(pd.CategoricalDtype(order, ordered=True))
df['_N'] = df.groupby('Attribute').cumcount()

df = df.sort_values(['_N', 'Attribute']).drop(columns='_N')
```

---

```
    clinic_id  client_id  patient_id       Attribute
0       97142       1891        3423    Service Date
6       97142       1891        3423         Product
3       97142       1891        3423             Qty
12      97142       1891        3423          Amount
15      97142       1891        3423             Age
9       97142       1891        3423  Days Last Dose
1       97142       1891        3423    Service Date
7       97142       1891        3423         Product
4       97142       1891        3423             Qty
13      97142       1891        3423          Amount
16      97142       1891        3423             Age
10      97142       1891        3423  Days Last Dose
2       97142       1891        3423    Service Date
8       97142       1891        3423         Product
5       97142       1891        3423             Qty
14      97142       1891        3423          Amount
17      97142       1891        3423             Age
11      97142       1891        3423  Days Last Dose
```

Comment: Checking this on large data